# Android Studio asking for SDK location - Win 7

Tags: android, sdk, location

I have been learning Android programming using Android Studio (v22.6.2-1085508), today suddenly Android Studio is asking SDK location.
I checked Android Studio -> Windows -> Preferences -> Android

SDK Location is empty.
Browse and tried -
c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_67
c:\Program Files\java\jre7
c:\Program Files(x85)\java\jre7

But looks not right.

I am not sure if it related to my recent update of java download?

Answer (score 0):

If it asks for SDK location it is most likely the Android SDK you need to provide (which is the top level directory of your Android SDK installation, containing *platorm-tools, samples*, etc.), not the Java JDK. The JDK would have its own location on the same window though.

If you also need to provide the JDK path, if you have JDK 7 installed at *c:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_67*, you can provide that path there.

My configuration (File -> Project Structure... -> SDK Location):
[image]